# WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) vs WEEK('2018-05-1') - the current date

Tags: mysql

just wondering if anyone can shed some light on why why the following query (Note: today's date is 1 May 2018)

**SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());** gives a result of **18**.

BUT the query:
**SELECT WEEK('2018-05-1')** (using all the different modes 0 -7) gives a result of **17**?

Shouldn't the week of year for NOW() technically be the same as the week of the year for: 2018-05-01 since today is the 5th of May 2018?

Very curious as to why its not giving the same result.

Many thanks

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear),`week(date, 3)` should be equivalent to `weekofyear(date)`.  The real issue here is that a given year can sometimes have more than 52 weeks, depending on boundary conditions.  So it isn't always nice and clean, as you might expect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen a yes. that makes sense now. I just assumed a year always had 52 weeks.

Comment: Also note that `NOW()` includes the current hour whereas `'2018-05-1'` not (I would also suggest using the FORMAL form `'2018-05-01'`, meaning, two digits for month and two for day).

Answer (score 1):

In `weekoftheyear()` function, Week number will start from the 1st day of the year.

In `Week()` function, Week number will start from 1st Monday of the given year.