# How can I get the Date Equal to Today of week, month and year/lifetime?

Tags: mysql

I made reports with filter. The options are this week, this month and lifetime. My problem is it also picked up the next day. For example, the date today is Sep 04. If I select this week the output will be this `Sep 02 Mon, Sep 03 Tue, Sep 04 Wed, Sep 05 Thu, Sep 06 Fri, Sep 07 Sat, Sep 08 Sun`

I want this to happen...

```
Sep 02 Mon
Sep 03 Tue
Sep 04 Wed
```

Same with this month and lifetime...

```
  $sql="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tbl_date.date, '%b %d') AS Date_Request, 
  COUNT(tbl_request_order_details.request_order_id) AS Total_Order, 
  tbl_supplier.supplier_name AS Supplier FROM (tbl_date LEFT JOIN 
  tbl_request_order ON tbl_request_order.date_request = tbl_date.date AND 
  tbl_request_order.barangay_id = $_SESSION[barangay_id]) LEFT JOIN 
  tbl_request_order_details ON tbl_request_order.request_order_id = 
  tbl_request_order_details.request_order_id LEFT JOIN tbl_supplier_medicine 
  ON tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id = 
  tbl_request_order_details.supplier_medicine_id LEFT JOIN tbl_supplier ON 
  tbl_supplier.supplier_id = tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_id LEFT JOIN 
  tbl_barangay ON tbl_barangay.barangay_id = tbl_request_order.barangay_id 
  WHERE

            (";
                switch($search){
                    case 'lifetime':
                        $sql .= "(tbl_date.date between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() 
                 ,'%M-%d-01') AND NOW())) GROUP BY tbl_date.date
                            ORDER BY tbl_date.date;";
                            break;
                    case 'this_week':
                        $sql .= "YEAR(tbl_date.date) = YEAR(NOW())
                AND WEEKOFYEAR(tbl_date.date) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()))
                            GROUP BY tbl_date.date
                            ORDER BY tbl_date.date;";
                            break;                  
                    case 'this_month':
                        $sql .= "YEAR(tbl_date.date) = YEAR(NOW())
                AND MONTH(tbl_date.date) = MONTH(NOW())) 
                            GROUP BY tbl_date.date
                            ORDER BY tbl_date.date;";
                            break;                 
                }
            ")";
```

Comment: where is your query?

Comment: @Vel I already edit my post you can see above

Comment: In WEEKOFYEAR() function, Week number will start from the 1st day of the year.

In Week() function, Week bymber will start from 1st Monday of the year.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110900/weekofyearnow-vs-week2018-05-1-the-current-date

Comment: adding condition `tbl_date.date<=now()` should do the trick